# Difference between protected and having no access modifier

Tags: java, variables, public, protected

When declaring a variable in Java,what's the difference between "protected" and having "no access modifier"? Is it the same?

Comment: default is package-private access , protected - package access + all subclasses even if in other packages ! Go through [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) please !

Comment: The default access for interfaces and annotations is `public`  The default access for `class` and `enum` is package local.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### It isn't same.

Both **protected** and **no access modifier** variables are accessible in the same package, but **protected** variables can be accessed by a subclass instance anywhere (in any package).

Comment: Thanks that's the answer I was looking for!

Answer (score 6):

Go through the [Oracle tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html).

*If a class has no modifier (the default, also known as package-private), it is visible only within its own package*

*The protected modifier specifies that the member can only be accessed within its own package (as with package-private) and, in addition, by a subclass of its class in another package.*

```
Modifier    | Class | Package | Subclass | World
————————————+———————+—————————+——————————+———————
public      |   Y   |    Y    |    Y     |   Y
————————————+———————+—————————+——————————+———————
protected   |   Y   |    Y    |    Y     |   N
————————————+———————+—————————+——————————+———————
no modifier |   Y   |    Y    |    N     |   N
————————————+———————+—————————+——————————+———————
private     |   Y   |    N    |    N     |   N
```

[JLS 6.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6):

> if the member or constructor is **declared protected**, then access is permitted only when one of the following is true:
>
> 1. Access to the member or constructor occurs from within the package containing the class in which the protected member or constructor is declared.
> 2. Access is correct as described in §6.6.2.
>
> we say there is **default access**, which is permitted only when the access occurs from within the package in which the type is declared.

Answer (score 4):

No access modifier is known as "package private": all classes defined in the one package can access all things defined as "package private" in the same package.

Protected means all classes extending the class that defines the protected instance can access that instance.

Answer (score 0):

They are not same. If there is no access modifier specified then it is package private.

More details can be found in [java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

Answer (score 0):

No. The Default is Package-Private.  Which is slightly different than protected.

The default is in between private and protected, less strict than private, but more strict than protected.

[For more details here is the oracle page about it.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)